# Why Are Footer Styles Getting Cut Off?

Tags: css, sass

I have some social media links in the footer here that are styled to be in circles: https://milfordpa.us

Everything looks good on Chrome, but on Safari, the last one appears to get "cut off" and I can't seem to figure out why.

Here is my current SCSS:

```
  .social-links {
    display: block;
    float: right!important;
    a {
      border-radius: 50%;
      padding: 10px 11px;
      font-size: 20px;
      background: $color3;
      color: $color2;
      margin-left: 5px;
      &:hover {
        background: $color4;
        color: $color2!important;
      }
    }
    i {
      width: 21px!important;
      height: 20px!important;
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more code so that it would be possible to reproduce this scenario, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one of your parent elements for `.social-link` you're changing the width to something that safari seems to struggle with.

A quick fix is to reapply the width on `.social-link`

```
.social-link {
    text-align: right;
    min-width: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```